# libvirt kvm hidden state fail to validate

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization

Ubuntu 15.04
Fresh new installation so all packages are up to date.

Trying to edit libvirt xml file. Using $ sudo EDITOR=gedit virsh edit win81

Added

```
<kvm>
  <hidden state='on'/>
</kvm>
```

then receive following error message

```
error: XML document failed to validate against schema: Unable to validate doc against /usr/share/libvirt/schemas/domain.rng
Extra element devices in interleave
Element domain failed to validate content
```

Help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are trying to use a relatively new feature, perhaps it is not yet available in 15.04. It is available in 15.10 development. You can check by looking at `/usr/share/libvirt/schemas/domaincommon.rng`. Does it contain this:

```
  <!-- Optional KVM features -->
  <define name="kvm">
    <element name="kvm">
      <interleave>
        <optional>
          <element name="hidden">
            <ref name="featurestate"/>
          </element>
        </optional>
      </interleave>
    </element>
  </define>
```

If the feature is available, then please show us the bigger context of your .xml file. Perhaps edit your question and post the entire `<features>` section.

Comment: Thank you and yesterday it magically accepted the change without any modification. I now have more questions about vga passthrough <3

Comment: Also those lines were in the rng file